# How to catch a button click in WKWebView - objective c

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, wkwebview

I have been looking on the web since yesterday and have not found any solution so far, Can someone please assist. Thanks in advance.

I have a scenario where i am opening a web page in a "WKWebView" which is loading successfully but i want to catch a button click in objective c on a "WKWebview". i have the following code in my webpage.

```
function AddtoFavorite(id)
{
   var isAndroid = "0";
   var login = "0";
     if (isAndroid == "1") {
       if (login == "0")
        {
          Android.checkLogin();
         } 
       else {
         favourite(id);
         $.unblockUI();
         $("#loader").hide();
          }
    } else {
          favourite(id);
          $.unblockUI();
          $("#loader").hide();
      }
    }

    var favourite = function (id)
    {
        debugger;
        $.get("/Home/AddtoFavorite?id=" + id, function (data) {
            var isAndroid = "0";
        //alert(0);
            if (data == 0) {
                //alert("Please login/register.");
                bootbox.confirm({
                    message: "<h4>Please Login/Register to continue!!!</h4>",
                    buttons: {
                        confirm: {
                            label: 'Continue',
                            className: "button btn",
                        },
                        cancel: {
                            label: 'No',
                            className: 'cancelbutton'
                        }
                    },
                    callback: function (btn) {
                        if (btn == true) {

                            if (isAndroid == "1") {
                            }
                            else {
                                $.blockUI();
                            }
                            window.location.href = "/Account/SignIn"

                        }

                    }


                })
```

Now whenever user clicks on add to favourite icon, a pop up window appear on "WKWebView" stating Login/Register to continue, i don't want to show web pop up instead i want to show my own UIAlertController but i am unable to catch the action in a "WKWebView".

Can someone please assist.

Comment: i want to catch this pop up dialog in webview and wants to show my own custom alertcontroller, but the webview popup window should not be shown on the page.

Comment: Can you add a debug repo? I think I can make it work.

Comment: actually i don't know how to, so can you please assist without it

Comment: I mean you just need to create a demo project which has problem on your question. After that give me the link to download it.

Comment: hello, did you find a solution ?

Comment: Yes , we need to add webhandler trigger in HTML and catch the handler in our code. let me know if you need more details